# injecting and ember service from outside

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

Can I inject service to a component from an initializer? I would like to have a property in any component in my app's components that brings static config info. I know I can do this inside the component:

```
cfgStore: Ember.inject.service('cfgstore-reader')
```

And I can add an object to my components in an intializar:

```
let cfg = Ember.Object.extend(cfgStore);

export function initialize(application) {
  application.register('cfgstore:main', cfg);
  application.inject("component", "cfgstore", "cfgstore:main");
}
```

Can I do the same for an injector? I could find any sample and it does seem to work...

Comment: what do you mean by doing the `same for an injector`?

Comment: means injecting from an intializer rather than inside the component itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to inject service:

```
application.inject("component", "cfgstoreReaderService", "service:cfgstore-reader");
```